# Ponteiros para Funções

Tags: c, ponteiro, pic

Estou enfrentando um pequeno problema com ponteiros para funções em um programa para microcontroladores Microchip Pic Série 18.

O código apresenta os protótipos de duas funções envolvidas no problema e uma chamada para a função 'insere_tarefa', que DEVERIA receber o endereço da função 'tarefa1' por meio do parâmetro 'tarefa'.

Porém, estou depurando o código no Proteus Isis e o parâmetro 'tarefa' não recebe o endereço da função passada como argumento. Sendo mais específico, o parâmetro 'tarefa' não recebe absolutamente nada.

O que estou fazendo algo errado?

```
void insere_tarefa(uint8 prioridade, tipo_t tipo, void (*tarefa)());
void tarefa1();

insere_tarefa(0, 0, tarefa1);
```

O printscreen abaixo mostra o campo "value" do ponteiro "tarefa" sem nenhum valor durante a chamada da função "insere_tarefa".

Alguém já teve esse tipo de problema? Como resolveu?

[image: debug]

Comment: No [codepad](http://codepad.org/nlaZkqji) a função recebe valor.

Comment: @stdio.h uma dúvida boba. Poderia colocar a implementação dessa função? Poderia testar com o "&"? Para pegar o endereço, não sei vai mudar muita coisa.

Comment: @Wakim, já tentei usar o &. Não funcionou.
Parte da implementação da função aparece na figura acima.

Comment: Quero dizer a impl. da função passada por parâmetro.

Comment: É uma função de teste. É apenas um laço infinito que fica piscando um LED. O protótipo dela é mostrado no trecho de código que postei com a pergunta.

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda, mas acredito que o problema seja algum bug do Proteus.
Tentei depurar o código usando o depurador do MPLAB X e lá dá tudo certo.
Por algum motivo o Proteus não consegue encontrar o endereço de algumas funções.

Comment: Corrija o tipo de retorno da rotina (em mais de lugar, não esqueça), pois o compilador provavelemte não está encontrando a assinatura correta, mas não da erro de compilação.

Comment: @Isalamon, o tipo de retorno da rotina está correto. É uma função sem retorno, e o ponteiro para função que defini também é do tipo void.

Comment: No código que voce postou no codepad sua rotina tem isto: "return 42;" !!!!

Comment: @Isalamon, quem postou aquele código no codepad foi o pmg.